# Criterion based on boolean TSQL function

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

I'm calling the  sql server function Contains like this :

```
ftquery = _OrElse(ftquery,Restrictions.Eq(Projections.SqlFunction("contains",NHibernateUtil.Boolean, Projections.Property<Document>(d => d.SearchContent), Projections.Constant(query.Query)),true));
```

OrElse will juste do an or using Restrictions.Or(ICriterion, ICriterion). The problem is that it generates invalid sql :

```
... and contains(this_.SearchContent, ?) = ? ORDER BY ...
```

I don't want to have the right part ( = ? ), I only need the Projection without the Restrictions.Eq, but without Restrictions.Eq I can't find any solution to convert a Projection to a Criterion.

How can we using NHibernate generate an sql like :

```
Select Name from Users where Contains(Name,'toto') or Contains(Job,'tata')
```

Answer (score 0):

Register the function in your dialect:

```
RegisterFunction("FullTextContains", new StandardSQLFunction("contains", NHibernateUtil.Boolean));
```

Create a projection using `Projections.SqlFunction` then use this [ProjectionAsCriterion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33027662/1486443) class on your query:

```
var projection = Projections.SqlFunction("FullTextContains", 
    NHibernateUtil.Boolean, 
    Projections.Property<Document>(x => x.SearchContent),
    Projections.Constant(query.Query));

var result = Session.QueryOver<Document>()
    .Where(new ProjectionAsCriterion(projection))
    .List();
```